# TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError - How Do You Debug This‽

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, javascript

I've seen the question countless times on here, but it's always unique to the smart contract, so I feel like I need to ask it again.  This is based off of a smart contract I'm testing on Goerli.  I don't really know where to start with figuring out what's going wrong here, so let me just briefly describe the expected outcome.

I start with a javascript program that analyzes blockchain transactions to make determinations on profitable arbitrage paths.  These paths could be as long as 10 different trades inside a single transaction.  Once identified, the final function (shown below) sends the transaction to my published contract ([here is the link to the contract, partially pasted below](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xdccf7bd8943b67060582e05d99b13ce29ac134ff#code)) The smart contract is intended to execute the identified path as a series of trades starting with an AAVE flashloan and ending with its repayment.

So I'm not sure at this point whether there's something wrong with the way I'm sending the instructions, with the smart contract code or, most likely, both.  Here are the particulars:

```
The Error:

Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x3fedfbae76a371ad1d3da04a8c8d68b43bdb56a5750b6a5eec63ed6a9f176cf4",
  "blockNumber": 10305200,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 6054630,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 10,
  "from": "0xdf58ca0a02bf9b43ce13b8ab5969e4b60f22c0a3",
  "gasUsed": 24448,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0xdccf7bd8943b67060582e05d99b13ce29ac134ff",
  "transactionHash": "0x768ff8c1b59ea6b3014e464dbc9580ec722602548220063a4226b445bdd44ed6",
  "transactionIndex": 38,
  "type": "0x0"
}
    at Object.TransactionError (/Users/TrentKennelly/triBot/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:87:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (/Users/TrentKennelly/triBot/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:98:21)
    at /Users/TrentKennelly/triBot/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:396:57
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
}
```

```
The javascript function:

    const executeTrades = async (tradeInstructions, arbitrage, account) => {

    console.log(`Attempting Arbitrage...\n`)

    let arbAddr

    executed = false

    const firstToken = tradeInstructions[0].inputToken
    const firstTokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(IERC20.abi, firstToken)

    const balanceBefore = await firstTokenContract.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
    const ethBalanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(account)

    if (config.PROJECT_SETTINGS.isDeployed) {
        
        const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

        const tradeData = await arbitrage.methods.executeFlashLoan(
            tradeInstructions.map((instruction) => [
                instruction.arbPair,
                instruction.startOnUniswap,
                instruction.inputToken,
                instruction.outputToken,
                instruction.amountIn,
                instruction.amountOut
            ])
        ).encodeABI();

        const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
        const value = web3.utils.toHex(tradeInstructions[0].amountIn)
        const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const gasCalc = gasPrice.toString();
        if (config.PROJECT_SETTINGS.networkSetting === "g") {

            arbAddr = config.CONTRACTS.GOERLI
        
        } else if ( config.PROJECT_SETTINGS.networkSetting === "m" ) {
        
            arbAddr = config.CONTRACTS.MAINNET
        }

        const gasLimit = 200000 * tradeInstructions.length
        const estimatedGas = new web3.utils.BN(Number(gasLimit)).mul(new web3.utils.BN(gasPrice));//(web3.utils.toBN(gasLimit)).mul(new web3.utils.BN(gasPrice));  
        const gasCalcul = estimatedGas.toString();
        const estimatedGasCost = web3.utils.fromWei(gasCalc, 'ether')
    
        const rawTransaction = {
            from: account,
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasCalc),
            // gas: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
            gas: web3.utils.toHex(gasCalcul),
            to: arbAddr,
            value: value,
            data: web3.utils.toHex(tradeData),
        };

        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(web3.utils.toHex(serializedTx));

        web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, privateKey)
            .then(function(signedTransaction){
                web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction)
                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log("response:" + JSON.stringify(response, null, ' '));
                    })
            })

        executed = true

    }

    if (executed) {

        console.log(`Trade Complete:\n`)

        const balanceAfter = await firstTokenContract.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
        const ethBalanceAfter = await web3.eth.getBalance(account)

        const balanceDifference = balanceAfter - balanceBefore
        const totalSpent = ethBalanceBefore - ethBalanceAfter

        const data = {
            'ETH Balance Before': web3.utils.fromWei(balanceBefore, 'ether'),
            'ETH Balance After': web3.utils.fromWei(balanceAfter, 'ether'),
            'ETH Spent (gas)': web3.utils.fromWei((ethBalanceBefore - ethBalanceAfter).toString(), 'ether'),
            '-': {},
            'WETH Balance BEFORE': web3.utils.fromWei(balanceBefore.toString(), 'ether'),
            'WETH Balance AFTER': web3.utils.fromWei(balanceAfter.toString(), 'ether'),
            'WETH Gained/Lost': web3.utils.fromWei(balanceDifference.toString(), 'ether'),
            '-': {},
            'Total Gained/Lost': `${web3.utils.fromWei((balanceDifference - totalSpent).toString(), 'ether')} ETH`
        }

        console.table(data)
```

```
Smart contract code (just the contract itself):

contract ArbitrageFlashLoan {
    address public constant AAVE_LENDING_POOL_ADDRESS = 0x5E52dEc931FFb32f609681B8438A51c675cc232d; //goerli address
    address public uniswapV2Router;
    address public token0;
    address public token1;

    struct TradeInstruction {
        address arbPair;
        bool startOnUniswap;
        address inputToken;
        address outputToken;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOut;
    }

    TradeInstruction[] public tradeInstructions;

    uint256 public fee; // Fee to be charged for the flash loan

    IAaveLendingPool public lendingPool;

    event FlashLoanExecuted(address indexed token, uint256 profit);

    event UnprofitableTrade(address indexed token, uint256 loss);

    address private uniswapV2RouterAddress = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address private sushiswapRouterAddress = 0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506;

    constructor() {

        fee = 90; // Translating 0.9% into solidity code
        lendingPool = IAaveLendingPool(AAVE_LENDING_POOL_ADDRESS);
    
    }

    function executeFlashLoan(TradeInstruction[] memory _tradeInstructions) external {
                
        // Step 1: Initiate flash loan
        require(_tradeInstructions.length > 0, "No trade instructions added");

        address[] memory assets = new address[](_tradeInstructions.length);
        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](_tradeInstructions.length);
        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](_tradeInstructions.length);

        assets[0] = _tradeInstructions[0].inputToken;
        amounts[0] = _tradeInstructions[0].amountIn;
        modes[0] = 0; // 0 for no debt swap, 1 for debt swap

        lendingPool.flashLoan(
            address(this),
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            address(this),  // Use the same address for onBehalfOf
            abi.encodeWithSignature("executeTrades(TradeInstruction[] memory)", _tradeInstructions),
            0
        );
    }

    function executeTrades(TradeInstruction[] memory _tradeInstructions) external {

        require(msg.sender == address(lendingPool), "Only Aave Lending Pool can call this function");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _tradeInstructions.length; i++) {

            uint256 _amountIn;
       
            if (i == 0) {

                _amountIn = _tradeInstructions[i].amountIn;

            } else {

                _amountIn = _tradeInstructions[i - 1].amountOut;

            }

            executeOperation(_tradeInstructions[i].inputToken, _amountIn, _tradeInstructions[i]);
            
        }

        uint256 profit = _tradeInstructions[_tradeInstructions.length - 1].amountOut - _tradeInstructions[0].amountIn;

        // Repay flash loan and fee using the inputToken of the last trade instruction
        uint256 totalAmountToRepay = _tradeInstructions[_tradeInstructions.length - 1].amountOut + fee;
        IERC20(_tradeInstructions[_tradeInstructions.length - 1].outputToken).transfer(address(lendingPool), totalAmountToRepay);

        if (profit > 0) {
            // Profitable trade
            emit FlashLoanExecuted(_tradeInstructions[0].inputToken, profit);
        } else {
            emit UnprofitableTrade(_tradeInstructions[0].inputToken, profit > totalAmountToRepay ? 0 : totalAmountToRepay - profit); // Emit an event for logging purposes
            revert("Unprofitable trade"); // Revert the transaction with an error message
        }

    }

    function executeOperation(address _token, uint256 _amountIn, TradeInstruction memory tradeInstruction) private {
        require(_token == tradeInstruction.inputToken, "Invalid token");

        IUniswapV2Router02 router;
        
        if (tradeInstruction.startOnUniswap) {
            router = IUniswapV2Router02(uniswapV2RouterAddress);
        } else {
            router = IUniswapV2Router02(sushiswapRouterAddress);
        }

        // Swap inputToken for outputToken on Uniswap V2
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = tradeInstruction.inputToken;
        path[1] = tradeInstruction.outputToken;

        uint256[] memory amountsOut = IUniswapV2Router02(router).swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            uint256(0), // Set to 0 for minimum output
            path,
            tradeInstruction.arbPair, // Use arbPair address //address(this),
            block.timestamp + 300
        );

        tradeInstruction.amountIn = amountsOut[0];
        tradeInstruction.amountOut = amountsOut[1];

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is ridiculous, but I've finally determined that it was an address error.  I was calling the AAVE lending pool address on Goerli and trying to run a "WETH" Flashloan, but that address doesn't have any of that token on it.

Comment: regarding how to debug this - there are many tools like tenderly, openchain.xyz or simply `forge debug` command